# Windows Installer Version 4.5.6002 24433

Tags: windows-installer

I have a windows server 2008 SP2 machine that has all latest windows updates installed...almost 250 or so updates listed. I am trying to figure out what update, if any, that may have installed windows installer version 4.5 6002 24433. If i look at the [Released Versions List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/released-versions-of-windows-installer) , the version that's listed for Server 2008 SP2 is 4.5 6002 18005. I want to rollback to this released version. So trying to figure out what update i need to uninstall. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can we ask why you need this? I am no server guy, but I don't think this is possible unless you exclude a hell of a lot of updates. Maybe flesh out your scenario a little bit? Also, you might be better off posting on [serverfault.com](http://www.serverfault.com) (system administrators) rather than this coder-based community.

Comment: Hi Stein! This is in reference to another question you had answered for me [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53048312/msi-install-on-terminal-server-getting-error-custom-action-server-rejected-w) . This install team came back with - it works on another terminal server etc. So we figured the diff was this msiexec versions. The msi log showed some differences on the two machines and wanted to see if i could roll back to the version the install creation team had - which is 4.5.6002 18005 and compare apples to apples.

Comment: Modifying the custom action settings did not work then?

Comment: Install creation team did not modify anything since it worked for them on a terminal server :(. Hence i am trying to see whatever i can figure out. Most research points to KB3072630 - unfortunately that update is not on this machine though. Even rolling back to the 18005 version is just a troubleshooting step.

Comment: Sorry been a while but wanted to come back and share my findings: KB4340937 installs Windows Installer 4.5.6002.24433, KB4087398 installs Windows Installer 4.5.6002.24299, KB3196726 installs Windows Installer 4.5.6002.19424. We were able to rollback to 4.5.6002.18005 by uninstalling these windows updates. And this helped us resolve [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53048312/msi-install-on-terminal-server-getting-error-custom-action-server-rejected-w)

Comment: OK. I just checked that briefly - I have to say that those fixes look very important :-(. Are you sure this is the only way? At least protect the server by all means available.

Comment: After installing product, we were able to just apply all windows updates again. Interestingly though if you set up a new machine with Server 2008 and SP2 and apply all updates...it keeps windows installer at 4.5.6002.18005 and never even recommends any of those updates for Windows Installer. I am just happy to get this over with :)

Comment: OK. Windows Updates are crazy. I counted more than 600 updates on a Windows 7 machine before I ran a purge via `cleanmgr.exe` once. Windows 10 has cumulative updates at least. The number of deprecated updates on lower platforms is staggering. In the link that follows, open an item and go "`Package Details`". You can then see what newer updates deprecated the package in question: [KB4087398](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4087398). Just if someone else reads this at some point.